# Putting runnable to sleep

Tags: java, multithreading, notify

I have a problem with Java. I would like to write a program where there is Class Main which has ArrayList of Threads of some class (Class Task) which just writes a letter and the number. Object Main just wakes one Thread from ArrayList and let it to do something while the same object(Main) sleeps another one.

It works ok:
0A, 0B, 0C, 1B, 1C, 1A, 2B, 2A, 2C, 3B, 3C, 3A, 4B, 4C, 4A, 5B, 5A, 5C,

but only if i Comment the: 
   e.printStackTrace() e is Exception
then
I get lot of 
    java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
    at java.lang.Object.notify(Native Method)
    at Main.run(Main.java:22)

So the notify works wrong, how I should correctly wake it, please tell me, show, correct. PLease

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main extends Thread {
ArrayList<Thread> threads;

public Main() {
    super();
    threads = new ArrayList<Thread>();
}

public void run() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        threads.add(new Thread(new Task(i + 65)));
    }
    long cT = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int i = 0; i < threads.size(); i++) {
        threads.get(i).start();
    }
    while (System.currentTimeMillis() - cT < 10000) {
        for (int i = 0; i < threads.size(); i++) {
            try {
                threads.get(i).notify();
                // HOW TO WAKE THREAD FROM threads ArrayList
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                // how to put to bed the same thread ?
                threads.get(i).wait();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
     new Main().start();
    //new Thread(new Task(65)).start();

}

}
```

H

```
public class Task implements Runnable {
int nr;
char character;

public Task(int literaASCII) {
    this.nr = 0;
    character = (char) (literaASCII);
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        try {
            System.out.print(nr + "" + character + ", ");
            nr++;
            int r = (int) ((Math.random() * 500) + 500); // <500ms,1000ms)
            Thread.sleep(r);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}



public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

Comment: The above is practically entirely wrong headed.  What precisely are you trying to do?  Have a single Task thread work while the rest sleep?  And have the main thread sequentially make that happen for the Task threads?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`sleep` and `wait` are very different. `sleep` simply pauses the current thread for the specified amount of time, and has no direct interaction with other threads.

`wait` is more complicated: the idea of `wait` is to pause a thread *on a given monitor* (or lock, if you wish) and let other thread do work until it `notify`s on that monitor and releases it. So `wait` and `notify` involves interaction between two or more threads.

Because of this interaction, in order for `wait` and `notify` to work correctly, the thread which calls those methods must own the monitor (the lock), which means, that `object.wait()` or `object.notify()` must be called from within `synchronized(object){ ... }` block. If you call `object.wait()` without `synchronized`-block you will always get an `IllegalMonitorStateException`.

In your code,

```
for (int i = 0; i < threads.size(); i++) {
  threads.get(i).start();
}
```

this will start all threads and then will run them all at the same time, not one at a time as you want.

To make sure only one thread runs one at a time you will need to pass a common monitor object to all threads and have them `wait` on that monitor. For example:

```
public class Main extends Thread {
  //...

  public void run(){
    //Initialize all threads with common monitor object
    Object monitor = new Object();
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      threads.add(new Thread(new Task(i + 65, monitor)));
    }
    long cT = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int i = 0; i < threads.size(); i++) {
      //All threads will start, and immediately pause on monitor.wait()
      threads.get(i).start();
    }
    synchronized(monitor){
      while (System.currentTimeMillis() - cT < 10000) {
        //All threads are currently waiting, so we need to wake one random
        //thread up by calling notify on monitor. Other thread will not run yet,
        //because this thread still holds the monitor.
        monitor.notify();

        //Make this thread wait, which will temporarily release the monitor
        //and let the notified thread run.
        monitor.wait();
      }
    }
  }
}

//...

public class Task implements Runnable{
  int nr;
  char character;
  Object monitor;

  public Task(int literaASCII, Object monitor) {
    this.nr = 0;
    this.monitor = monitor;
    character = (char) (literaASCII);
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    synchronized(monitor){
      while (true) {
        //Pause this thread and let some other random thread
        //do the work. When other thread finishes and calls notify()
        //this thread will continue (if this thread is picked).
        monitor.wait();

        try {
          System.out.print(nr + "" + character + ", ");
          nr++;
          int r = (int) ((Math.random() * 500) + 500); // <500ms,1000ms)

          Thread.sleep(r);
        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //This thread has finished work for now. 
        //Let one other random thread know.
        monitor.notify();

        //Other thread will not be able to do work until this thread 
        //releases the monitor by calling monitor.wait() or 
        //completely exists the synchronized(monitor){ ... } block.
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It may behave slightly differently from your original intention, because threads will wake up randomly, so there is no guarantee the output will be in any particular order.

Also note that in general you should prefer `notifyAll()` to `notify()`, unless you have a very good reason to use `notify()`. Because `notify()` only wakes up one thread, if that thread "forgets" to call notify at the end, all other threads may `wait` forever.

Comment: Thank you, but how to make it work like that
A,A,...A(3000ms),B,B,B,B(3000ms)? The code is down the page

Comment: @RobertKilar Getting precise ordering might be quite complicated. I don't quite understand why you would want AAAABBBB with multiple threads. If you threads run one-at-a-time and in order, it is not really a multi-threaded program, is it? Just looks like a sequential program.

Comment: You should not try to *kill* threads. Instead, you should have a common flag to communicate the intention to stop to all threads. For example, create a `static boolean finished = false` in `Main` and set it to `true` when you want to stop processing. Then for each `Task` instead of `while(true){...}` use `while(!Main.finished){...}`. This way all threads should die by themselves when `run()` method finishes.

Answer (score 2):

In order to call wait() on an object, you have to hold the synchronized lock on that object (though the lock is actually released while the thread is waiting):

You can do the following thing where solution is achived.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main extends Thread {
    ArrayList<Thread> threads;

    public Main() {
        super();
        threads = new ArrayList<Thread>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            threads.add(new Thread(new Task(i + 65)));
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < threads.size(); i++) {
            threads.get(i).start();
        }

    }

    public void run() {
        long cT = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while (System.currentTimeMillis() - cT < 10000) {
            for (int i = 0; i < threads.size(); i++) {
                try {
                    synchronized (threads.get(i)) {
                        threads.get(i).notify();
                        // HOW TO WAKE THREAD FROM threads ArrayList
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                        // how to put to bed the same thread ?
                        threads.get(i).wait();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main().start();
        // new Thread(new Task(65)).start();

    }

}

class Task implements Runnable {
    int nr;
    char character;

    public Task(int literaASCII) {
        this.nr = 0;
        character = (char) (literaASCII);
    }

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                System.out.print(nr + "" + character + ", ");
                nr++;
                int r = (int) ((Math.random() * 500) + 500); // <500ms,1000ms)
                Thread.sleep(r);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to synchronize on the thread you want to wait():

```
synchronized(threads.get(i)) {
    // how to put to bed the same thread ?
    threads.get(i).wait();
}
```

Comment: Because the specification documentation says so: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait()

Answer (score 0):

Ok I corected it so it's now:
But i get on console

0A, 0B, 0C, 0D, 0E, 1A, 1B, 1C, 1D, 1E, 2A, 2B, 2C, 2D, 2E, I stop 10
I stop 11
I stop 12
I stop 13
I stop 14
I stop 15

But i would rather like sth like 0A,1A(A works for some time for 3000ms) then the other runs for 3 secs etc. not like A,B,C,D,E,A, but more like A,A,A,B,B,B....

But also i just can't kill this threads, there is never ending loop, I'd like to kill it while Main is dying.

Thank you for all your comments

import java.util.ArrayList;

```
public class Main extends Thread {
ArrayList<Thread> threads;

public Main() {
    super();
    threads = new ArrayList<Thread>();
}

 public void run(){

Object monitor = new Object();
for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
  threads.add(new Thread(new Task(i + 65, monitor)));
}
long cT = System.currentTimeMillis();
for (int i = 0; i < threads.size(); i++) {
  threads.get(i).start();
}
synchronized(monitor){
  while (System.currentTimeMillis() - cT < 10000) {
      try{

    monitor.notify();
    Thread.sleep(50);


    monitor.wait();}catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
  }

for(int i = 0; i < threads.size(); i++){
    System.out.println("I suspend "+threads.get(i).getId());
    threads.get(i).stop();
}


}
 }


 public static void main(String[] args) {
     new Main().start();
    //new Thread(new Task(65)).start();

}

}
```

H

```
public class Task implements Runnable {
int nr;
char character;
Object monitor;

public Task(int literaASCII, Object monitor) {
    this.nr = 0;
    this.monitor = monitor;
    character = (char) (literaASCII);
}

@Override
public void run() {
    synchronized (monitor) {
        while (true) {

            try {
                monitor.wait();

                System.out.print(nr + "" + character + ", ");
                nr++;
                int r = (int) ((Math.random() * 500) + 500); // <500ms,1000ms)

                Thread.sleep(r);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            monitor.notify();

        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: If you want A,A,A,B,B,B,C,C,C it is complete nonsense to do it in more than one thread (if threads make sense at all for your purpose). If it is absolutely necessary to use threads you have to do all work of A before you start B or you check in B's task if A is done and put it back to sleep if not.